# java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListIterator.next android

Tags: java, android, database, sqlite

I have update from database using set status method when click button to getting error i have send to array list to next activity while getting error 
**I'm new in android programming**

```
 ImageButton ibAddMore = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.ibAddMore);
    ibAddMore.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                                     @Override
                                     public void onClick(View v) {
                                         DataBaseHelper db = new DataBaseHelper(getApplicationContext());
                                         for (People people : alertList) {//In this Line getting error
                                             if (people.getStatus() == 1) {
                                                 db.setStatus(people.getId(), "0");
                                                 alertList.add(people);
                                             } else {
                                                 db.setStatus(people.getId(), "1");
                                             }
                                         }
                                         Intent intent = new Intent(AlertList.this, AlertListAll.class);
                                         startActivity(intent);
                                     }
                                 }

    );
```

**Set Status Method**

```
 public int setStatus(String peopleId, String status) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    values.put(STATUS, status);

    return sqLiteDatabase.update(TABLE_PEOPLE, values, ID + "=?",
            new String[]{peopleId});

}
```

**Exception:**

```
java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
at java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next(AbstractList.java:62)
at com.Jaydeep.alertme.activity.AlertList$1.onClick(AlertList.java:67)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4240)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:17721)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5136)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:737)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2):

you can't modify the same collection you are looping on directly. But you can do it using a [ListIterator](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ListIterator.html). E.g.

```
for (ListIterator<People> iterator = alertList.listIterator(); iterator.hasNext(); ) {//In this Line getting error
     People people = iterator.next();
     if (people.getStatus() == 1) {
        db.setStatus(people.getId(), "0");
        iterator.add(people);
     } else {
        db.setStatus(people.getId(), "1");
     }
}
```

Comment: i have put your code some error like this:-java.util.AbstractList$SimpleListIterator.next

Comment: post the whole stacktrace

Comment: check my whole trace @Blackbelt

Comment: do you still have `alertList.add(people);`  ?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding elements to the same list while you are iterating. It's more java than android.

Btw why you want to add the same element again to the list you are iterating thru ?